# Ubuntu 20.10, USB headset detected, microphone working, but headphones not working

Tags: sound, headphones, headset

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Laptop and when plugging in an USB headset ("Sennheiser PC 8.2 USB") it is detected and auto-switched to (headphones and microphone). The microphone is working. But there's no sound on the headphones (on detection they make a short "click" noise, so they seem to be operated shortly). The buttons on the headset cable are working ("+/-" make Ubuntu move the sound level bar).

Packages are fully up to date and I already rebooted. Sound and microphone built into the laptop are working OK. The headset is fully working on another Ubuntu 20.10 laptop and on a Windows 10 desktop PC as well.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Install pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control) which has more control than standard configurator :
`sudo apt install pavucontrol` 
Run it and check  :

- "output devices" tab to select usb  (click the green button near USB device to make it default)
- "playback" tab:   also   select usb for running audio apps
- "configuration" tab : search any "usb" profile (may exist or not).

Comment: Today came a pulseaudio update and it made that all output comes from the laptop internal speakers, no matter if I selected the headset or the internal speakers. Microphones still worked normally. With `pavucontrol` I deactivated all other output devices and then it worked. However this seems as a workaround (I'd like to have it work smooth and not have to fidle with thsi tool all the time), I will not accept this answer yet and wait some time.